# Can you just point someone in the right direction and how vague are you allowed to be with this?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

I recently asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704765/how-to-execute-a-command-in-multiple-terminals-by-executing-a-command-in-only-on/), and [this was](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704765/how-to-execute-a-command-in-multiple-terminals-by-executing-a-command-in-only-on/704771#704771) one of the answers I got:

> I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.03, so YMMV. Investigate some of these
>   packages:
>
> ```
> $ apt-cache search ssh | grep multiple
> byobu - powerful, text based window manager and shell multiplexer
> vcsh - Version Control System for $HOME - multiple Git repositories in $HOME
> capistrano - Executes commands in parallel on multiple servers
> clusterssh - administer multiple ssh or rsh shells simultaneously
> fail2ban - ban hosts that cause multiple authentication errors
> mssh - tool to administrate multiple servers at once
> ruby-net-ssh-multi - Ruby library for making multiple SSH connections to remote systems
> sslh - ssl/ssh multiplexer
> ```

I mean I know you don't have to do all of the work for the other person and that you can sort of point them in the right direction, but how vague is too vague? Because the person isn't even sure if any of these packages will work... I don't think so, but as it hasn't been deleted yet, would this be considered an acceptable answer?

Comment: I noticed the answer as well, had the same thought.  You *could* flag it as "low quality".

Comment: Personally, I consider an answer something that the OP and others with the same problem can follow in order to reach a solution.  I'm sure I've been guilty of leaving "bread crumb" trails in comments and short answers on occasion, but I try to provide answers that even the uninitiated can follow. At the end of the day it's a judgement call.

Comment: @ElderGeek: What type of bread do you use?

Comment: Available bread of course. ;-)

Comment: @ElderGeek If there is too little time to post a "real" answer, or if you just want to give a hint, post a comment. Someone else can possibly use the information in an answer then. Remember an answer is not only meant for OP, but should be extensive enough to be of use for future visitors.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Agreed. See my comment Dec 3 at 19:10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should substantially answer the question, always. It's even on the Answering page of the help center:

> Read the question carefully. **What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative.** The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

That was a clear cut case of NAA, and it has been deleted.

Comment: Thank Braiam. I think I'm going to use NAA in everyday conversation now!